# Vaadin ComboBox popup sizing Issue

Tags: combobox, vaadin, vaadin8

I am having an issue with the Vaadin 8 ComboBox.I want to adjust the PopUp page according to the no. of records . Because since the default value is 10 and say if I am having 41 records , I am being left with almost a blank page with only one record at the last page . Is there any way to fix this ?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to check [ComboBox.setPageLength(x)](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.5.1/com/vaadin/ui/ComboBox.html#setPageLength-int-) method

JavaDoc states:

> Sets the page length for the suggestion popup. Setting the page length to 0 will disable suggestion popup paging (all items visible).

Comment: Yeaa !  I actually used that method and changed the page length dynamically based on the input. Thanks!